# How to indent text inside literal string?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to get literal output with a line break, and then an indentation, so that the result would look like this:

```
int write(const std::string sFileName, int iStep, float fStartTime,
          const std::string sInfoString, int iWhat
```

But when i use this

```
| ``int write(const std::string sFileName, int iStep, float fStartTime,
| ``          const std::string sInfoString, int iWhat,``
```

i get

```
int write(const std::string sFileName, int iStep, float fStartTime,
`` const std::string sInfoString, int iWhat,``
```

I also tried a unicode substitution for non-breaking space:

```
 .. |xx| unicode:: U+00A0
```

But this is not being substituted:

```
| ``int write(const std::string sFileName, int iStep, float fStartTime,
| ``|xx||xx||xx|const std::string sInfoString, int iWhat,``
```

results in

```
int write(const std::string sFileName, int iStep, float fStartTime,
|xx||xx||xx|const std::string sInfoString, int iWhat
```

How can achieve the indentation i want between the double back-quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [`code-block` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-code-block). Indentation will be rendered relative to the first line of code.

```
.. code-block:: c++

    int write(const std::string sFileName, int iStep, float fStartTime,
              const std::string sInfoString, int iWhat
```

Also I don't know what language you use, but you can substitute the proper lexer for `mylang` by looking it up on the [Pygments lexers page](https://pygments.org/docs/lexers/).

### Edit

Updated to use the [lexer `c++`](https://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#pygments.lexers.c_cpp.CppLexer).

Comment: Thanks. With ``.. code-block:: c++`` i get the result i want.